# How to create legend (continuous colourbar) based on specific range of values in R/ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I have a dataframe named `myKrige_new` contains some latitude-longutude wise interpolated values. You can download from [HERE](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByY3OAw62EShOG44MUtJeGFxeU0). I have plotted this values on a particular area of a country map using `ggplot2` package in R and I got this plot
[image]

But I want the legend(colourbar) of my plot would be like the following legend.

[image]

In my dataset here, the range of the data (pred) is 72 to 257. But I want my legend would show the value 0 to 200 because of comparing reason with other plot though there no value under 72 here .

So, I want to use 20 different colour like above legend that means last box of legend would contain colour regarding value greater than 200. I have used `scale_fill_gradientn` function but it didn't work. I have spend days to find some option to do it in R, didn't get success. Any kind of help will be highly appreciable.

R code :

```
library(scales)
library(ggplot2)

myKrige_new <- read.csv ("myKrige_new.csv")

range(myKrige_new$LON) 
range(myKrige_new$LAT)

#Original skorea data transformed the same was as myKrige_new
skorea1 <- getData("GADM", country= "KOR", level=1)
skorea1 <- fortify(skorea1)  
myKorea1 <- data.frame(skorea1)

###############
ggplot()+ 
  theme_minimal() +
  #SOLUTION 1:
  #geom_tile(data = myKrige_new, aes(x= LON, y= LAT, fill = pred)) +

  #SOLUTION 2: Uncomment the line(s) below:
  #geom_point(data = myKrige_new, aes(x= LON, y= LAT, fill = pred),
  #shape=22, size=8, colour=NA)+ 

  #Solution 3
  stat_summary_2d(data=myKrige_new, aes(x = LON, y = LAT, z = pred),bins = 30,
                  binwidth = c(0.05,0.05)) +

  scale_fill_gradientn(colours=c("white","blue","green","yellow","red"),
                       values=rescale(c(0,50,100,150,200)),
                       guide="colorbar", name = "PM10 Conc")+ 
  geom_map(data= myKorea1, map= myKorea1, aes(x=long,y=lat,map_id=id,group=group),
           fill=NA, colour="black") +

  coord_cartesian(xlim= c(126.6, 127.2), ylim= c(37.2 ,37.7)) +
  labs(title= "PM10 Concentration in Seoul Area at South Korea",
       x="", y= "")+
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")+
  guides(fill = guide_colourbar(barwidth = 27, barheight = NULL,
                               title.position = "bottom", title.hjust = 0.5))
```

Comment: Set `scale_fill_gradientn( ... , guide = 'legend', ... )` instead of `colorbar`, though the result varies a little by geom.

Comment: Sorry, I can't figure it out!  Actually I want to show different color for different range of values and legend would show the range of color 0 to 200.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a working solution:

```
library(scales)
library(ggplot2)
library(raster) # needed for the `getData` function
library(dplyr)  # needed for the `mutate` funtion

myKrige_new <- read.csv("~/Downloads/myKrige_new.csv")[-1]

range(myKrige_new$LON) 
range(myKrige_new$LAT)

# Original skorea data transformed the same was as myKrige_new
skorea1 <- getData("GADM", country= "KOR", level=1)
skorea1 <- fortify(skorea1)  
myKorea1 <- data.frame(skorea1)

# the range of  pred goes above 200 (max = 257)
summary(myKrige_new$pred) 

ggplot() + 
  theme_minimal() +
  stat_summary_2d(data = mutate(myKrige_new,
                                pred = ifelse(pred > 200, 200, pred)),
                  aes(x = LON, y = LAT, z = pred),
                  bins = 30,
                  binwidth = c(0.05,0.05)) +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours=c("white","blue","green","yellow","red"),
                       values=rescale(c(0,50,100,150,200)),
                       name = expression(paste(PM[10], group("[",paste(mu,g/m^3), "]"))),
                       limits = c(0,200),
                       breaks = seq(0,200, 20),
                       guide = guide_colorbar(nbin = 20,
                                              barwidth = 27,
                                              title.position = "bottom",
                                              title.hjust = 0.5, 
                                              raster = FALSE,
                                              ticks = FALSE)) + 
  geom_map(data= myKorea1,
           map= myKorea1,
           aes(x=long,y=lat,map_id=id,group=group),
           fill=NA,
           colour="black") +
  coord_equal(xlim= c(126.6, 127.2),
              ylim= c(37.2 ,37.7)) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0)) +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0,0)) +
  labs(title = "PM10 Concentration in Seoul Area at South Korea",
       x = "",
       y = "") +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

I added `limits = c(0,200)` and `breaks = seq(0, 200, 20)` to `scale_fill_gradientn` as well as `nbin = 20` to `guide_colorbar`, this last change is optional because the default `nbin` is 20, but in your case you actually need 20. Also, adding `limits` means values outside the range are plotted in grey50 so I had to transform *pred* values above 200 to 200 to avoid that; the interpretation of red color is now 200+.

One more thing, the option `raster` in `guide_colorbar` changes the colorbar from a raster object to a set of rectangles achieving the look you were looking for.

Finally, I changed the coordinate system from cartesian to equal because you are plotting a map.

Here is the result hope it helps:

[image: korea]

Update: added a `expand` argument to `scale_y_continuous` and `scale_x_continuous` as requested by OP

Comment: wow! Thanks a lot donlelek! if you don't mind, one more thing I am struggling with. You can see , some portion of map extended outside of my plot on right and bottom side. Is there any way to remove/cut this extended portion?

Comment: Hi @Orpheus, just edited the answer to address that issue, you have to include `expand = c(0,0)` to the axis you want to crop.

Comment: Dear @donleke, How can I add some text on this plot? I want to write "PM10 [µg/m3] : 2012/03/28/23 KST" on my plot. (10  & 3 in PM10 and m3 would be subscript).  I tried like this:
`annotate("text", label = expression(paste(PM[10], group("[",paste(mu,g/m^3), "]")):2012/03/28/23~KST), x = 311000, y = 4173500, size = 6, colour = "white", fontface = c("bold"))`  but it gave me `error :invalid 'type' (expression) of argument`

Comment: Hi @Orpheus, there was more than one problem with that piece of code, first `geom_text` doesn't accept expressions, they have to be strings and you have to add `parse = TRUE`, second your x and y are on a different scale, I guess you switched to UTM and last, the brackets were misplaced, the following code should solve your issues. 1 of 2

Comment: 2 of 2 `annotate("text",
           label = "PM[10]~group('[', mu*g/m^3, ']')*':'*2012/03/28/23*'~'*KST",
            x = 127,
            y = 37.5,
            parse = TRUE,
            size = 6,
            colour = "black",
            fontface = "bold")`

Comment: yeah, perfectly working but it shows plain font. why the fontface not getting bold?